# Does official IOS development course exist?

Tags: ios

I'm a newbie in IOS development. And I would like to know, is there official course of IOS development(preferable on Swift) like [android official course at UDacity built by Google](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nope but you should check out the design guidelines [here.](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/)

Comment: Paul Hegarty also has a good course every year at Stanford, you can watch it in Itunes U

Comment: Thanks for an advice.

Comment: There is no any official course, but you can go to http://www.raywenderlich.com and learn by tutorial from there, also you can use many programming guides available at developer.apple.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is no any official course, but you can go to raywenderlich.com
>   and learn by tutorial from there, also you can use many programming
>   guides available at developer.apple.com - Mehul Thakkar

And there is a good course on Coursera by University of Toronto.